# GCC: _Static_assert "non-constant condition for static assertion"

Tags: c++, c, gcc, reinterpret-cast, static-assert

I have larger C code base, where I want to integrate some C++ code. The C++ code needs some declarations from the C code base.

Compiler is currently GCC 6.3.1, but we might be able to update the compiler.

Basically, the included C headers contain code like this:

```
#define NRF_GPIO  ((int*)          0x0000112233)
static_assert(NRF_GPIO == NRF_GPIO, "asd");
```

This compiles fine, if the compiler compiles C files, but fails, if the code is written in C++, as the reinterpret cast will not yield in a constant expression and the compiler correctly complains about it:

```
error: non-constant condition for static assertion
 static_assert(NRF_GPIO == NRF_GPIO, "asd");
                        ^
t.cpp:2:20: error: reinterpret_cast from integer to pointer
 #define NRF_GPIO  ((int*)          0x0000112233)
                   ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
t.cpp:3:15: note: in expansion of macro 'NRF_GPIO'
 static_assert(NRF_GPIO == NRF_GPIO, "asd");
```

Is there a way to let the GCC compile the C++ a little bit more relaxed and thus to except the code above?

Comment: I guess your real code doesn't check that a preprocessor symbol is equal to itself. If you would show a real example it might be easier to propose a workaround. Can you use two macros, e.g. `#define NRF_GPIO_ADDR 0x0000112233` and `#define NRF_GPIO ((int*) NRF_GPIO_ADDR)` and use `NRF_GPIO_ADDR` for the assertion?

Comment: If you have a C header that you cannot use with C++ code, you need to make a separate C++ header (or tell the creator of the C header to add some `#ifndef __cplusplus` to make it a C/C++ header)

Comment: @Bodo Of cause, the real, failing assert does some more magic, but in the end, it really boils down to the given example. If I could tell gcc to have this assert in C++ the same as it handles it in C, my problem would have been solved.

Comment: @Artyer well duplicated code is not really an option and I want to change the existing C code as little as possible (preferable, I don't want to change the code at all).

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki If it boils down to the example, then the condition will always be true and there's no need for a `static_assert`.

Comment: suggestion: write a C implementation, wrapping the critical foreign headers and a C/C++ compatible header for this. Then Write your C++ code including only your own (compatible) header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not guaranteed to work in C either. In C the static assertion requires an *integer constant expression*, which may contain casts to non-integer types only as part of `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operands.

C does permit an implementation to allow other forms of *constant expressions*, but at least with the current C23 working draft it has been clarified that this does not affect the validity as *integer constant expression*. See [N2713](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2713.htm).

GCC also warns about that with `-pedantic`.

You generally can't invent out-of-thin-air pointer values and use them at compile time in C++ (except for null pointer values). C allows slightly more, but not in contexts requiring *integer constant expressions*. See below.

The only way to work with this is to keep the address as a numeric value at compile-time and convert it to a pointer only at runtime when it is needed as such.

There is one exception in C, but not C++: An integer constant can be cast to a pointer and be used as an *address constant* to constant-initialize a variable. However even then the address constant cannot be an operand to `==` (or most other operators) in the initializer expression, nor is it allowed in an *integer constant expression*.

Comment: Thanks, this would also explain, why the C example fails to compile with a newer version of clang.

Comment: C recognizes NRF_GPIO as constant address. See [6.6p9](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p9) "integer constant cast to pointer type". Still comparison of those two is not "arithmetic constant expression".

Comment: @tstanisl My understanding is that this is only relevant to constant-initialization of variables, not `_Static_assert`, but it is really a minor difference to C++. In C++ such an _address constant_ cast from an integer constant would not be considered a constant expression and may therefore have dynamic initialization. I have mentioned it in the answer.